# Popcorn will never stop

Tags: riddle

```
If a man says duck
It all turns black

Will the ball explode
with doom and gloom?

The bell will ring
And the child will sing

When you see a cow
???
```

Options:

1. The horse knows why
2. You want it too
3. It turns to snow
4. They find a shack
5. Your eyes turn green

---

#### Hints:

(it's already solved but in case you want to try anyway)

1.

> Every two lines are separate, and follow the same logic

2.

> An alternate ending for the first line is:
>  
>     If a man says duck
>  
>    *goo ga goo ga gack*

3.

> The semantics of the second line is irrelevant

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 2. You want it too

Reason:

> The last word in the second line of each couplet rhymes with the sound made by the last word in the first couplet.
>
> If a man says **duck** (quack)
> It all turns black
>
> Will the ball **explode** (boom)
> with doom and gloom?
>
> The bell will **ring** (ding)
> And the child will sing
>
> When you see a **cow** (moo)
>  **You want it too**

Comment: Oh, good catch!

Comment: why not snow then? cow->snow?

Comment: @Sid rot13(Zbb qbrfa'g eulzr jvgu fabj.)

Comment: Whoa you're good :)

Comment: @Dotan Just one thing I don't get: what does the title signify?

Comment: @Randal'Thor popcorn sounds like 'pop' which rhymes with stop

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> 2. You want it too

Reasoning:

> The title gives it away: popcorn goes *pop* = stop

Here is the explanation:

> You take the last word of each first line, and rhyme the onomatopoeia that is associated with that word

- > Duck -> quack = black
- > Explode -> boom = gloom
- > Ring -> ring/ding = sing
- > Cow -> moo = too

Comment: You're quite correct, but the answer has already been posted by as4s4hetic.

Comment: I did figure out the title though